# window.location.href not working in chrome and ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I was trying to redirect a page using jquery but it is not working.
I tried to use all the falvors:

```
      window.location.href = url;
      location.href = url;
      window.location = url;
      location = url;
      window.location.assign(url);
```

my code is:

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
                btnsubmit = $("#btnLogin");
                btnsubmit.click(function () {
                     var uName = $("#userName").val();
                     var uPass = $("#pasWord").val();
                     var str = -1;
                     $.ajax({
                          type: "Post",
                          async: false,
                          url: "Default.aspx/userLogin",
                          data: '{"userName":"' + uName + '","userPassword":"' + uPass + '"}',
                          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                          dataType: "json",
                          success: function (response) {
                                    str1 = response.d;
                                    str = str1;
                          },
                          failure: function (msg) {
                                    alert("Please contact your administrator");
                           }
                 });
                  redirectUser(str);
               });
               redirectUser = function (str) {
                              if (str == 0) {
                                    alert("Hello you have not yet been verified.\nPlease contact your supervisor for the same.");
    }
    else if (str == 1) {

        alert("You have been approved by your supervisor.\nBut the admin has not approved you yet.");
    }
    else if (str == 2) {
        document.write("You will be redirected to main page in 5 sec.");
        setTimeout(redirect_changePassword(), 5 * 1000);
    }
    else if (str == 3) {
        document.write("You will be redirected to main page in 5 sec.");
        setTimeout(redirect_approved(), 5 * 1000);
                }
    else if (str == 4) {
                    alert("You have been rejected by your Supervisor.\nPlease contact your supervisor for the same.");
    }
    else if (str == 5) {

        alert("You were approved by your supervisor.\nBut the admin has rejected you.\nPlease contact your supervisor for the same.")
    }
    else if (str == 6) {
        document.write("You will be redirected to main page in 5 sec.");
        setTimeout(redirect_admin(), 5 * 1000);
    }
    else if (str == 7) {
        alert("Some unkonwn error has occured.\nPlease contact your administrator.");
    }
    else if (str == 8) {
                    alert("Wrong credentials");
    }
    else if (str == 9) {
                   alert("Some unkonwn error has occured.\nPlease contact your administrator.");
    }
}

redirect_changePassword = function () {
    var nextUrl = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/ChangePassword.aspx';
    window.location.href = nextUrl;
}
redirect_approved = function () {
    var nextUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/UserHome.aspx";
    //window.location.href = nextUrl;
    window.location.assign(nextUrl);
    return false;
}
redirect_admin = function () {
    var nextUrl = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/AdminHome.aspx";
    window.location.href = nextUrl;
}

     });
```

please help me to solve the problem
if I write the url and then try then also it is not working.
even it is not redirecting to google.

Comment: You've to prevent the default action when submitting a form, that way `location` object will work. Notice, that a function executed after the page has been parsed is not a correct place for `dw()`s.

Comment: But the firm has ti be submitted to check username n password

Comment: Looks like you're already sending the values with AJAX. When a browser is ready to submit a form (or ready to do any "trip" to server), `window.location` is blocked.

Comment: From having a first look on your code, it seems that the `redirectUser` function gets called before the ajax request is complete. You should use `promise` or `deferred` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of javascript `Promise` or jQuery `Deferred` object

```
var promise = new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
                      type: "Post",
                      async: false,
                      url: "Default.aspx/userLogin",
                      data: '{"userName":"' + uName + '","userPassword":"' + uPass + '"}',
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function (response) {
                                str1 = response.d;
                                str = str1;
                      },
                      failure: function (msg) {
                                alert("Please contact your administrator");
                       }
});

promise.then(function success() {
      redirectUser(str);
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  But str is being passed with 3 and it enters the function redirect_approved but still not redirecting

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this example? Replace your ajax request by some static code , `str = 3;` so as to work upon it.

Answer (score 0):

according to your code redirectUser(str) function is called before ajax is executed. You can keep redirectUser(str) in done of ajax. So, str will  have -1.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "Post",
      url: "Default.aspx/userLogin",
      data: '{"userName":"' + uName + '","userPassword":"' + uPass + '"}',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
           str1 = response.d;
           str = str1;
       },
      failure: function (msg) {
         alert("Please contact your administrator");
      }
    }).done(function(){
        redirectUser(str);
    });
```

Comment: Str is being passed with value and I get the string in nexturl but still no luck

Comment: have you done console.log(str) in function. Is value is printing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error and solved it by using the following code:

```
      document.write("You will be redirected to main page in 5 sec.\n" + "<script>window.location.href ='http://google.com'; </script>");
        //but this was not working because you have already passed data to headers, but not the redirect code.
        setTimeout(redirect_approved(), 5 * 1000);
```

actually the new page was created and hence the page redirect was not working